# Using vue-router gives "Cannot find element #app" and "TypeError: Cannot read property 'matched' of undefined" errors

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vue-router

I am attempting to use Vue.js to recreate a frontend app I previously made using Scala Play (I'd like to learn more about component-based web design).

I had everything loading fine for the first page I made, but I wanted to implement routing so I could have multiple pages (rather than just having one big single-page application). I installed vue-router using `npm install vue-router --save`, and am trying to follow the following tutorial (using the components I've already made though): https://scotch.io/tutorials/how-to-build-a-simple-single-page-application-using-vue-2-part-1.

As far as I can tell, everything *should* be loading smoothly, but nothing loads and I get the following console errors:

```
[Vue warn]: Cannot find element: #app
[Vue warn]: Cannot find element: #app
[Vue warn]: Error in render: "TypeError: Cannot read property 'matched' of undefined"

found in

---> <App> at src/App.vue
       <Root>

TypeError: Cannot read property 'matched' of undefined
    at render (vue-router.esm.js?8c4f:76)
    at createFunctionalComponent (vue.runtime.esm.js?2b0e:3033)
    .... (etc)
```

I've not pasted the full stack traces but can do if needed.

My code is below:

**main.js**

```
import Vue from 'vue'
import App from './App.vue'
import VueRouter from 'vue-router'

import Home from './components/Home.vue'

Vue.use(VueRouter)

const routes = [
  { path: '/', component: Home }
]

const router = new VueRouter({
  routes
})

new Vue({
  el: '#app',
  template: '<App/>',
  components: { App },
  router
}).$mount('#app')

Vue.config.productionTip = false

new Vue({
  render: h => h(App),
}).$mount('#app')
```

**App.vue**

```
<template>
  <div>
    <router-view></router-view>
  </div>
</template>

<script>

export default {
  name: 'app'
}
</script>

<style>
  * {
    box-sizing: border-box;
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
  }
  body {
    font-family: Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
    line-height: 1.4;
    background-color: aliceblue;
  }
</style>
```

**components/Home.vue**

```
<template>
  <div id="app">
    <Header />
    <Posts v-bind:posts="posts" />
  </div>
</template>

<script>

import Posts from './Posts.vue'
import Header from './Header.vue'

export default {
  name: 'home',
  components: {
    Header, Posts
  },
  data() {
    return {
      posts: []
    }
  }
}
</script>

<style>
</style>
```

Let me know if I need to include Header.vue and Posts.vue too - I've omitted them because they were rendering fine before I tried to use vue-router.

How do I get rid of these console errors so my home page renders correctly when using vue-router? I have searched around and so far, all of my search results have led me to some variation on "make sure `router` is lowercase" (it is), "make sure `routes` is lowercase" (it is), and "use `import Vue from 'vue/dist/vue.js'`" (didn't work).

Comment: Try to remove `.$mount('#app')` since `el:"#app"` does the job and also remove `id="app"` from `<div id="app">` inside `App.vue`

Comment: @BoussadjraBrahim that got rid of my console errors, but nothing is rendering on the page. I noticed that the `<div id="app"></div>` that everything is meant to be inserted into (from index.html) is missing when I look at the Elements on my page - see my screenshot [here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/AoHJi.png) vs [here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/H0Btj.png). Will this have anything to do with it? I'm not sure why the div is disappearing...

Comment: In `main.js` you're creating two `App` components and mounting them at `#app`. You only need the first—I assume that's your issue.

Comment: if it's possible try to reproduce your code [`here`](https://codesandbox.io/s/j2qnlw756v)

Comment: @DarraghEnright I fixed my errors by cutting out the larger `new Vue` section (the first one) and putting the router in there. I have no idea why this is now working without all the `el: '#app', template: '<App/>', components: { App }` stuff though, so if you added an answer which explains that I'd be happy to accept it (as it was your comment which led me to fix my issue) - or feel free to edit my answer to contain an explanation. Otherwise, I appreciate everyone's help on this.

Comment: Hi @JamesWhiteley - I added an answer that will hopefully clarify some of your questions.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With regard to the original issue:

As I am sure you know from the comment discussion, the errors `[Vue warn]: Cannot find element: #app` were caused because two Vue instances were configured to mount—one after another—at the same root DOM node `#app`.

The first Vue instance mounts, and in doing so, *replaces* the root DOM node with the HTML defined in its own template. Therefore, the `#app` root DOM node no longer exists, and the second Vue instance fails to mount because it cannot find any DOM node with id `#app`.

<sub>This implies that if the first Vue template included a DOM node with id `#app`, the second Vue instance would probably mount there, replacing any existing HTML from the first instance with its own.</sub>

This error is resolved by removing the duplicate Vue instance.

---

With regard to your follow-up question:

> I don't have the faintest idea why this works without all the `el: '#app', template: '<App/>', components: { App }`

The first thing to note is that Vue instance property [`vm.$el`](https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/api/#vm-el) and Vue instance method [`vm.$mount()`](https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/api/#vm-mount) are functionally equivalent for the most part—each allows you to specify the root DOM element where the Vue instance will be mounted.

The main difference is in their application:

- You use `vm.$el` to declare the root DOM node at instance creation. Supplying a value is not obligatory however, and if you don't the instance is created in an *unmounted state*.
- `vm.$mount()` allows you to specify a root DOM node for an unmounted instance *after* instantiation.

As stated in the docs:

> If a Vue instance didn’t receive the el option at instantiation, it will be in “unmounted” state, without an associated DOM element. vm.$mount() can be used to manually start the mounting of an unmounted Vue instance.

Of course, if you use `vm.$mount()` instead of `vm.$el` at instance creation, this is largely a matter of developer taste (although `$mount()` does also accept a variety of inputs so there are other subtle differences there). But from the perspective of your question, there is no practical difference.

Finally, Vue's `template` property and `render()` method are simply two strategies for defining the template structure of a Vue instance:

- `template` is the higher-level template abstraction that allows you to define a *string template*; e.g: `<div><App/></div>` which Vue parses into a structure, instantiating any child components as required.
- `render()` is an alternative, lower-level template abstraction that is a [closer-to-the-compiler alternative to templates](https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/guide/render-function.html). It is more flexible for finer-grained/programmatic use-cases or for use with other template languages such as JSX or raw JS.

The main obvious difference in your examples is that `template` defines a string template using the `<App/>` component. The Vue instance needs to know what this component is before this template string is parsed, so it must be declared as a component.

Whereas, `render()` allows the `App` component to be passed for render directly, so it is not required to define a `template` property or declare any components.

My outlook is that the former is more explicit—which is not a bad thing—and is more declarative and readable when declaring a structure with several components. To that end, Vue seems to recommend template strings for most usage. That said, the latter approach can also be neat, and you'll often see it where a single, top-level, entry-point component (e.g: `App`) is being mounted.

<sub>Another (implicit) strategy is the *DOM template*. In the absence of a `template` property or `render()` method, the HTML structure defined within the root DOM node is used—although this is generally discouraged.</sub>

Hope this helps :)

Comment: This is fantastic, thank you! Makes much more sense now.

Comment: No problem @JamesWhiteley — glad to hear it was useful :)

Answer (score 0):

I fixed the issue by cropping down my main.js to only contain one `new Vue` section, which looks like this now:

```
new Vue({
  router,
  render: h => h(App)
}).$mount('#app')
```

I don't have the faintest idea why this works without all the `el: '#app', template: '<App/>', components: { App }` stuff though, so if that could be explained I'd appreciate it - I was hesitant to add an answer as I don't know *why* this worked; if someone adds an answer explaining it I'd be happy to accept that (or feel free to edit my answer with an explanation and cut this paragraph out).

Answer (score 0):

I found that the issue could be missing

```
<div id="app"></div>
```

at the body of your index.html.